# Multiple conditions in 2 different columns

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-statements, multiple-columns

I need to loop thru 9 sets of conditions

[image: Starting table - New GM is column it will loop through to get the answers using the 9 sets of conditions.]

[image: Here are the 9 sets of Conditions the loop has to run through]

Here are the 9 sets of Conditions the loop has to run through
I have tried If Statements with Select Case. I've tried without Select Case and use ElseIf.
I seem to be the most stuck on the writing the structure of the conditions asking the code to look at values in 2 different columns to determine the action.

I'm also struggling on the loop, but if I can get the conditions right, I think I can figure out the looping issue.

Here is the latest version of the code... (incomplete)
*****Do not worry about the action part of the code. this is a sample table of the data I'm working with.*****

```
Sub Margin_Five()

Dim i As Integer

'Set i = Range("M7")

'i = i + 1 'Start i off as 1

Dim lastRow As Long 'object creation
    lastRow = Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Dim ws As Worksheet, MyCell As Range
Dim BasedOn As Range

Dim AcctMgr As Range
Dim NewCost As Range
Dim Chgs As Range

    Set AcctMgr = Range("L:L")
    Set NewCost = Range("R:R")
    Set Chgs = Range("F:F")
    Set BasedOn = Range("X:X")

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set Chgs = ws.Range("F:F")
    i = i + 1
    For Each MyCell In (ws.Range("M7:M" & lastRow).Cells

        If Sheets(3).Range("L7") > 0 Then
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]"
                i = i + 1
        ElseIf Sheets(3).Range("F7") = "Removed" And Sheets(3).Range("X7") = "L" Then
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=(1-(RC[5]/RC[12]))*100"
                 = i + 1
        ElseIf Sheets(3).Range("F7") = "Removed" And Sheets(3).Range("X7") Then
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=(1-(RC[5]/(RC[7]/(1-RC[10]/100))))*100"
                i = i + 1
        ElseIf Sheets(3).Range("F7") = "Removed" And Sheets(3).Range("X7") Then
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=(1-(RC[5]/(RC[7]/(1-RC[10]/100))))*100"
                i = i + 1
        ElseIf Sheets(3).Range("F7") = "Removed" And Sheets(3).Range("X7") Then
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "N/A"
                i = i + 1
        End If
    Next MyCell

End Sub
```

Comment: Use a points system. L=2, M=3, R=4, B=5, "Removed" = 0, "Cost Chg" =4. Add them together.

Comment: I'm not certain I fully understand. Can you provide an idea of what you mean?

Comment: Are there some columns hidden in the screenshot ? if the first column is F then Based On is in M not X as your code ie `Sheets(3).Range("X7") = "L"`

Comment: no hidden columns. the tables are not actual data. I'm trying to figure out the structure in which to write the conditions. the columns mentioned in the code would not directly apply to the this table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build a dictionary of the 8 formula strings and use exists to select the appropriate one.

```vb
Sub Margin_Five()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, lastrow As Long, i As Long
    Dim dict As Object, key As String
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    ' margin calc
    With dict
        .Add "Removed-L", "=(1-(RC[5]/RC[12]))*100"
        .Add "Removed-M", "=(1-(RC[5]/(RC[7]/(1-RC[10]/100))))*100"
        .Add "Removed-R", "=(1-(RC[5]/(RC[7]/(1-RC[10]/100))))*100"
        .Add "Removed-B", "N/A"
        .Add "Cost Chg-L", "=(1-(RC[5]/RC[12]))*100"
        .Add "Cost Chg-M", "=(1-(RC[5]/(RC[7]/(1-RC[10]/100))))*100"
        .Add "Cost Chg-R", "=(1-(RC[5]/(RC[7]/(1-RC[10]/100))))*100"
        .Add "Cost Chg-B", "N/A"
    End With
   
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    With ws
        lastrow = .Range("I" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 7 To lastrow
            ' combine2 conditions in key
            key = .Cells(i, "F") & "-" & .Cells(i, "X")
            If .Cells(i, "L") > 0 Then ' sales pref
                ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]"
            ElseIf dict.exists(key) Then ' other 8 options
                ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = dict(key)
            End If
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```